# Does pidof works in crontab?

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to do a crontab to check if a process is running and if he doesn't I relaunch it via a script on a server (my script is cloning a repo and reconfiguring everything), here is the crontab line:

```bash
* * * * * bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0 && if [[ -z "$(pidof my_process)" ]];then curl my_url | bash;fi"
```

When I launch the command in my terminal, it works perfectly but in crontab I don't know why but it doesn't launch it, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: modify your crontab entry to append all stdout and stderr to a log file (eg, `* * * * * bash -c "..." >>/my/home/dir/crontab.log 2>&1`; once the crontab has fired (and done nothing), review the log file for any useful (error) messages that may shine a light on why it's not starting

Comment: `export DISPLAY=:0`? Are you trying to run a graphical application via a cronjob?

Comment: Why are you using `&&` after the `export` command? It can't fail, so there's no need to test it.

Comment: @Cyrus, it was a try i'm not really trying to run a graphical app but I was desperately trying

Comment: @markp-fuso I already try it but nothing was in the log file

Comment: change to `bash -c "set -vx; export DISPLAY=:0 && if [[ -z "$(pidof my_process)" ]];then curl my_url | bash;fi" > /path/to/logs 2>&1` so you'll have *something" in  your logile. Good luck.

Comment: If you are on Linux, run `ps -ef|grep -w cron` to verify that `cron` service is running. Then run `grep -i cron /var/log/*` to see if there are any (error) messages relating to `cron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the confusion but I've found out what that the cronie service was not running so everything work now, thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

There doesn't seem to be much point to piping your curl output to bash.  So, why not simply

```
curl my_url
```

For any command

```
"${this_command}" "${my_url}"
```

the proper form for the pidof usage is of the form

```
$(pidof "${this_command}")
```

so, your command should be

```
$(pidof curl)
```

Is that what you are using?

Lastly, by definition, cron jobs are "**headless**".  Unless the command sequence includes a utility (something like **xmessage**) to open a window on the specified display (**your script does not do that**), and that the command sequence is able to confirm that display is active and accepting "output" (i.e. a popup), the definition of **DISPLAY=:0** serves no purpose whatsoever (*that definition **will not open** a display which is not already open*), and all output goes to the cron logs.